# MongoDB average number per hour

Tags: database, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, aggregate

Is there a way to get the average count of **tickets** per hour within date range in MongoDB?

Here's an example of my record:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5a8e2f423c2df300143de0f8"),
  "ticket_number" : 58,
  "name" : "Test Name",
  "fb_id" : "1777532692279135",
  "inquiry" : "sample",
  "inquiry_date" : ISODate("2018-02-22T02:47:30.272Z"),
  "status" : "CLOSED",
  "__v" : 0,
  "assessment" : " sample",
  "assessed_by_name" : "Test Admin",
  "assessment_date" : "2018-02-22T02:48:17+00:00"
}
```

And this is my code that counts tickets per hour but it doesn't seem to work:

```
db.tickets.aggregate(
  {$match:{inquiry_date:{$gte: ISODate("2018-01-01T03:20:42.079Z"), $lt: ISODate("2018-04-25T03:20:42.079Z")}}},
  {$group:{ _id : { ticket_number: "$ticket_number", inquiry_date: "$hour" }, perHour: {$sum: "$count"} } },
  {$sort:{perHour:-1}}
)
```

Hoping someone could help me on this. Thanks!

Comment: what kind of output you want?

Comment: Just the _id (which is mandatory) and the average @AnthonyWinzlet

Comment: Try `{$group:{ _id : { ticket_number: "$ticket_number", inquiry_hour: {"$hour": "$inquiry_date"}}, perHour: {$sum: "$count"} } },`

Comment: perHour doesn't seem to work on my end. Is there another way where I can count tickets per hour? I have tried  `perHour: { $sum:1 }` @Veeram

Comment: I dont see why it wont work. Did you include the part `inquiry_hour: {"$hour": "$inquiry_date"}` ?

Comment: I did. Here's a sample response: `{
    "_id" : {
        "ticket_number" : 151,
        "inquiry_hour" : 6
    },
    "perHour" : 0
}` @Veeram

Comment: `perHour: {$sum:1}` should work. Are you trying this in mongo shell ?

Comment: The value is always 1. perHour value should be counting the documents with same inquiry_hour. Yes, I am trying it using mongo shell

Comment: Can you please show me the complete query that you are running ? It seems more like a debugging/data problem. Also just run `db.tickets.aggregate(
  {$match:{inquiry_date:{$gte: ISODate("2018-01-01T03:20:42.079Z"), $lt: ISODate("2018-04-25T03:20:42.079Z")}}})` to see if see values as expected.

Comment: I think I got it. `aggregate(
  {$match:{inquiry_date:{$gte: ISODate("2018-01-01T03:20:42.079Z"), $lt: ISODate("2018-04-25T03:20:42.079Z")}}},
  {$group:{ _id : {"$hour": "$inquiry_date"}, perHour: {$sum: 1} } }
)`. Is there a way where I could get the average of these documents? So the output would be `{ _id: "average", ave: 15.50  }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below aggregation in 3.6.

Mulit level [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) to get count and average across all documents followed by  [`$concatArrays`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concatArrays/) to merge the data with average document and [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) and  [`$replaceRoot`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/) to promote the merge document to the top.

```
  {"$group":{"_id":{"$hour":"$inquiry_date"},"perHour":{"$sum":1}}},   
  {"$group":{"_id":"average","data":{"$push":{"Hour":"$_id","perHour":"$perHour"}},"ave":{"$avg":"$perHour"}}},
  {"$project":{"all":{"$concatArrays":["$data",[{"ave":"$ave"}]]}},
  {"$unwind":"$all"}
  {"$replaceRoot":{"newRoot":"$all"}}
```

Comment: Last question, is it possible to include only the data from specified date range? I have tried adding `{$match:{inquiry_date:{$gte: ISODate("2018-01-01T03:20:42.079Z"), $lt: ISODate("2018-04-25T03:20:42.079Z")}}},` but it ruins the result

Comment: Looks right to me. Can you explain what is not working for you ?

Comment: When I add the `$match`, it returns multiple documents with the hour as id instead of returning 1 document with the adjusted average (because of the date range)

Comment: Can you show me the expected response ? do you expect the response to be `{"1":{perHour:2}, "2":{perHour:3} .... ,"avg":4}` ?

Comment: Expected response would be the same response from the solution you posted. `{
    "_id" : "average",
    "data" : [ 
        {
            "Hour" : 12,
            "perHour" : 1.0
        }, 
        {
            "Hour" : 17,
            "perHour" : 2.0
        }, 
        {
            "Hour" : 9,
            "perHour" : 6.0
        }        
    ],
    "ave" : 3
}`. I just wanted to add a date range on the query.

Comment: Got it. Remove all stages after second group.

Comment: Adding `$match` and removing `$project, $unwind, and $replaceRoot` produces the same multiple document response

Comment: Can you show me the whole query ? It should produce only 1 document.

Comment: `db.tickets.aggregate(
{"$match":{"inquiry_date":{"$gte": ISODate("2018-01-01T03:20:42.079Z"), "$lt": ISODate("2018-04-25T03:20:42.079Z")}}},
 {"$group":{"_id":{"$hour":"$inquiry_date"},"perHour":{"$sum":1}}},  
 {"$group":{"_id":"average","data":{"$push":{"Hour":"$_id","perHour":"$perHour"}},"ave":{"$avg":"$perHour"}}}, 
{"$project":{"all":{"$concatArrays":["$data",[{"ave":"$ave"}]]}}},
 {"$unwind":"$all"},
 {"$replaceRoot":{"newRoot":"$all"}} 
)`

Comment: Sorry I can't see your problem. It should return only 1 document when you remove all stages after second group.  Please feel free to create separate question.

Comment: It's very weird. Nonetheless, thank you so much for helping!